# Importing images to react as they generate

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx

I am generating images sequentially that I want to display in my react app. Currently I am importing the images, as shown below, but I am getting an import error, since the later images don't exist yet.

```
import image1 from '../output/img1.jpg';
import image2 from '../output/img2.jpg';
```

I have a solution which isn't very elegant: I could have placeholder images, I could download the generated images somewhere else, wait for those generated images appear elsewhere, download those generated images to the React app, and then display the downloaded image once my app sees that the image exists in both places.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: at what point you create this image? is it related to component which your are loading ?

Comment: I create the image after the react app has loaded. My Image needs to be imported from within the src file in order to be displayed, but if the images aren't there yet I get an import error.

Comment: try using import in componentDidMount, and catch error with if or something if the image is not in there

Comment: @GursharnSingh I'm getting an error that import may only appear at the top level.

Comment: oh sorry, yea that would happen, I don't know this would be best solution but do this, in componentDidMount declare a const like " const logo = require("../urImagePath.png");" then in img src use src={logo} ... all this is to cater for the wait we have to do to let your image to be created